# How to use Apache OpenNLP in a node.js application

Tags: multithreading, node.js, apache, architecture, opennlp

What is the best way to use Apache Open NLP with node.js?

Specifically, I want to use Name Entity Extraction API. Here is what is says about it - the documentation is terrible (new project, I think):

http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind

From the docs:

> To use the Name Finder in a production system its strongly recommended
>   to embed it directly into the application instead of using the command
>   line interface. First the name finder model must be loaded into memory
>   from disk or an other source. In the sample below its loaded from
>   disk.

```
InputStream modelIn = new FileInputStream("en-ner-person.bin");

try {
  TokenNameFinderModel model = new TokenNameFinderModel(modelIn);
}
catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
  if (modelIn != null) {
    try {
      modelIn.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

> There is a number of reasons why the model loading can fail:
>
> Issues with the underlying I/O
>
> The version of the model is not compatible with the OpenNLP version
>
> The model is loaded into the wrong component, for example a tokenizer
>   model is loaded with TokenNameFinderModel class.
>
> The model content is not valid for some other reason
>
> After the model is loaded the NameFinderME can be instantiated.

```
NameFinderME nameFinder = new NameFinderME(model);
```

> The initialization is now finished and the Name Finder can be used.
>   The NameFinderME class is not thread safe, it must only be called from
>   one thread. To use multiple threads multiple NameFinderME instances
>   sharing the same model instance can be created. The input text should
>   be segmented into documents, sentences and tokens. To perform entity
>   detection an application calls the find method for every sentence in
>   the document. After every document clearAdaptiveData must be called to
>   clear the adaptive data in the feature generators. Not calling
>   clearAdaptiveData can lead to a sharp drop in the detection rate after
>   a few documents. The following code illustrates that:

```
for (String document[][] : documents) {

  for (String[] sentence : document) {
    Span nameSpans[] = find(sentence);
    // do something with the names
  }

  nameFinder.clearAdaptiveData()
}

the following snippet shows a call to find


String sentence = new String[]{
    "Pierre",
    "Vinken",
    "is",
    "61",
    "years"
    "old",
    "."
    };

Span nameSpans[] = nameFinder.find(sentence);
```

> The nameSpans arrays contains now exactly one Span which marks the
>   name Pierre Vinken. The elements between the begin and end offsets are
>   the name tokens. In this case the begin offset is 0 and the end offset
>   is 2. The Span object also knows the type of the entity. In this case
>   its person (defined by the model). It can be retrieved with a call to
>   Span.getType(). Additionally to the statistical Name Finder, OpenNLP
>   also offers a dictionary and a regular expression name finder
>   implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout this NodeJS library.
https://github.com/mbejda/Node-OpenNLP
https://www.npmjs.com/package/opennlp

Just do **NPM install opennlp**

And look at the examples on the Github.

```
var nameFinder = new openNLP().nameFinder;
nameFinder.find(sentence, function(err, results) {
    console.log(results)
});
```